# Backend RTE htmlarea insert image missing from fresh TYPO3 install

Tags: typo3, tsconfig

I installed version 6.0.1 (blank package) and cannot insert images via this editor.

The image icon is missing from the toolbar.

TScript:

```
RTE.default.proc {
  allowTags := addToList(object,param,embed,img,iframe)
  allowTagsOutside := addToList(object,embed,img,iframe)
  entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to also enable the button using TSconfig:

```
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(image)
```

Also you need to turn in "Enable images" in the extension configuration (extension manager).

Answer (score 3):

For TYPO3 6.2 do the following:

1. In Extension Manager open the configuration of *htmlAREA RTE* and **enable** *basic.enableImages*.
2. In page-TSconfig add the following TypoScript:

   ```
   RTE.default {
       ## Enable the image button
       showButtons := addToList(image)

       ## Tags allowed outside p and div
       ## Adding img tag to the default list
       proc.allowTagsOutside := addToList(img)

       ## Do not remove img tags
       proc.entryHTMLparser_db.tags.img >
   }
   RTE.default.FE.showButtons < RTE.default.showButtons
   RTE.default.FE.proc.allowTagsOutside < RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside
   RTE.default.FE.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.tags.img >
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to TSConfig of your root page:

```
RTE.default.toolbarOrder := addToList(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to extensions, and configure `rtehtmlarea` extension.
Toggle `Enable images in the RTE` option.